# Segmentation fault while trying to add an item at the end of a linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

When I try to add an item at the end of a linked list it says segmentation fault (core dumped)

Here is the code

```
LinkedList :: LinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

void LinkedList :: InsertItem(int data)
{
    Node *new_node;
    new_node = new Node;
    new_node -> data = data;
    new_node -> next = NULL;

    new_node -> next = head;
    head = new_node;

    cout<<"Node Added"<<"\n";
}


void LinkedList :: Display()
{
     Node *curr;
     curr = head;

    while(curr != NULL)
    {
    cout<<curr->data<<"\t";
    curr = curr -> next;
    }
}

void LinkedList :: AddLast(int data)
{
     Node *new_node = new Node;
     new_node -> data = data;
     new_node -> next = NULL;

     Node *curr = head;
     while (curr != NULL)
     { 
    curr = curr -> next;
     }

     curr -> next = new_node;

}
```

When I run this, it says

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I am trying to implement this linked list without a tail node. So how should I do it?

Comment: Your `while(curr != NULL)` loop will keep executing until `curr` is NULL... which means that after the loop finishes executing, you're guaranteed that `curr == NULL`.   And yet, you try to dereference `curr` anyway (via `curr->next = new_node;`), so you crash.

Comment: Then what should I do? pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `AddLast` method, your iteration stops when `curr == NULL`. So when you attempt

```cpp
curr -> next = new_node;
```

you get a segfault, since `curr` is null here.

To fix this, change your iteration to

```cpp
while (curr->next != NULL)
```

That will ensure that the iteration stops at the last node, just like you need it to.